# Bulk change password of users in AD through powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to change password of multiple users in my AD through powershell script which I have written. In my AD, I have added an attribute called tempPassword which takes unicode string, which contains random generated password for all users. I want to write this tempPassword attribute as the user password. For this, my powershell script is:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -properties * -Filter *
foreach($user in $users)
{
    $password = $user.tempPassword
    $secure_string_pwd = convertto-securestring -String $password -asplaintext -force
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user -NewPassword $secure_string_pwd
}
```

When i execute this script, I get the following error:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' to the type 'S
ystem.String' required by parameter 'String'. Specified method is not supported.
```

The passwords contain numbers, lower and upper case characters and are all of length 8.

What may be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how `tempPassword` is defined in AD. However from what you receive, it means you get a collection of elements.

Try this:

```
$password = $user.tempPassword[0]
```